Playback Notification with Exoplayer3 Android Kotlin
I want to tell you about a problem I'm facing, I need to make a playback notification that will be bound to ExoPlayer. I managed to show the notification, but after showing it, the player stopped working (no sound plays, pause and resume don't work either). I used MediaSessionService to create the service.
I also managed to make my notification work, but the default media3 playback notification started to be shown

Service:
package com.drjay.core.utils.service

import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import androidx.media3.common.Player
import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSession
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService
import com.drjay.core.utils.SimpleMediaNotificationManager
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import javax.inject.Inject

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MusicPlayerService : MediaSessionService(),
  Player.Listener {
  
  @Inject lateinit var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer
  private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null
  
  @UnstableApi
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, exoPlayer).build()
    SimpleMediaNotificationManager(applicationContext, exoPlayer).startNotificationService(this)
  }
  
  override fun onDestroy() {
    mediaSession?.run {
      exoPlayer.release()
      release()
      mediaSession = null
    }
    
    super.onDestroy()
  }
  
  override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    val exoPlayer = mediaSession?.player!!
    if (!exoPlayer.playWhenReady
      || exoPlayer.mediaItemCount == 0
      || exoPlayer.playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED
    ) {
      stopSelf()
    }
  }
  
  override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo) = mediaSession
}

Notification manager:
package com.drjay.core.utils

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.OptIn
import androidx.media3.common.Player
import androidx.media3.common.util.NotificationUtil
import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService
import androidx.media3.ui.PlayerNotificationManager
import com.drjay.MainActivity
import com.drjay.R

class SimpleMediaNotificationManager(val context: Context, val player: Player) {
  
  fun startNotificationService(
    mediaSessionService: MediaSessionService,
  ) {
    buildNotification()
    startForegroundNotification(mediaSessionService)
  }
  
  @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
  private fun buildNotification() {
    val notificationManager =
      PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, 111, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setChannelImportance(NotificationUtil.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        .setSmallIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_logo_small)
        .setPauseActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_pause)
        .setPlayActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_play_small)
        .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.app_name)
        .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.app_name)
        .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(audioDescriptor)
        .setNotificationListener(notificationListener)
        .build()
    
    notificationManager.apply {
      this.setUseRewindAction(false)
      this.setUseFastForwardAction(false)
      this.setUsePreviousAction(false)
      this.setUseNextAction(false)
      this.setUsePlayPauseActions(true)
      this.setUseFastForwardActionInCompactView(true)
      this.setPlayer(player)
      this.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
      this.setColorized(true)
    }
  }
  
  @UnstableApi private val notificationListener = object : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {
    override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int, dismissedByUser: Boolean) {
      super.onNotificationCancelled(notificationId, dismissedByUser)
      if (player.isPlaying) {
        player.stop()
        player.release()
      }
    }
  }
  
  private fun startForegroundNotification(mediaSessionService: MediaSessionService) {
    val notification = Notification.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
      .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
      .build()
    mediaSessionService.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    Log.e("aga1", "startForegroundNotification: ", )
  }
  
  @UnstableApi private val audioDescriptor = object : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
    override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player): CharSequence {
      return context.getString(R.string.app_name)
    }
    
    override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player): PendingIntent? {
      return pendingIntent()
    }
    
    override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player): CharSequence {
      return "Body Scan exercise"
    }
    
    override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
      player: Player,
      callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback
    ): Bitmap? {
      return null
    }
  }
  
  private fun pendingIntent(): PendingIntent? {
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(
      context,
      0,
      intent,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
  }
  
  companion object {
    private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 200
    private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "notification channel id 1"
  }
}

Exoplayer initialization in fragment
  override fun initView() {
    super.initView()
    
    exoPlayerManager.initPlayer()
    exoPlayerManager.setStateListener(this)
    
    val sessionToken = SessionToken(requireContext(), ComponentName(requireContext(), MusicPlayerService::class.java))
    val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(requireContext(), sessionToken)
      .setApplicationLooper(Looper.getMainLooper())
      .buildAsync()
    
    controllerFuture.addListener({
    
   
    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
  MediaController.releaseFuture(controllerFuture)  // default media3 notification not showing
  }

Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />

  <application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DrJay"
    tools:targetApi="31">

    <activity
      android:name=".ui.boarding.BoardingActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
      android:exported="true"
      tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi,LockedOrientationActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
      android:exported="true"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi,LockedOrientationActivity" />

    <service
      android:name=".core.utils.service.MusicPlayerService"
      android:exported="true"
      android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
      tools:ignore="ExportedService">

      <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

  </application>

</manifest>

If I change 1 line I get the default media3 playback notification and my notification, if I leave it as shown above, the default notification disappears, my notification remains, but it doesn't work.
   val sessionToken = SessionToken(requireContext(), ComponentName(requireContext(), MusicPlayerService::class.java))
    val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(requireContext(), sessionToken)
      .setApplicationLooper(Looper.getMainLooper())
      .buildAsync()
    
    controllerFuture.addListener({
      MediaController.releaseFuture(controllerFuture)  //edited line (showing default media3 notification but my notification not working)
      
    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())


You can take a look at the demos and see if you find something useful there for this case
